# Payroll table creation challenge - Fill rows with various text requirements and repetition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

In the "Payroll export" worksheet, I need to take the data in `columns C through AL`, and convert it to what I've built `columns AN through AR`.

I have used an Array formula to paste the property, names, GL account, which are all the same, then another paste for the individual cost per property. This needs to be repeated 12 times. The reason for this is so that I can build the pivot tables.

My question / challenges are:

- Is there a single formula that would allow me to specify whatever is in cell X3, repeat in cells AN6:AN100, and Y3 repeat in cells AN101:AN200, and Z3 repeat in cells AN201:A300?
- Is there a single formula to repeat values in cell C3:C100, 12 times in column AO?

[Payroll table challenge](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PaMPM-2hx-87lz4E3_ynDZ5l0WDbNfLOPCo8uYuJyY8/edit#gid=155758848)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PaMPM-2hx-87lz4E3_ynDZ5l0WDbNfLOPCo8uYuJyY8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]!   Take the site [Tour] and review [ask].   While links can be helpful, your question should include the information needed to answer.  [Edit] the question to include some minimal sample data and your expected result.  Convert copied cells/tables from Sheets to [proper markdown format](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables). Tools like the [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) can make this easier.  Include relevant formulas describing that did/didn't work including any errors you encountered.

Comment: _"single formula to repeat values in cell C3:C100, 12 times in column AO"_ Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Stack Repeated Values Arrays

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({ 
   IFERROR(AN6:AN100/0, X3);
   IFERROR(AN101:AN200/0, Y3);
   IFERROR(AN201:A300/0, Z3) 
 })
```

- Divide every value in a range by 0 to return an array of `#DIV/0!` errors.
- IFERROR replaces each error with the value in the referenced cell.

##### Multi-Line Formulas

- I add spaces between arguments and split long formulas across multiple lines for stylistic reasons.
- In Sheets I find them easier to review and edit.
- Here it helps reduce the need to scroll back and forth to see the complete formula in a code block.
- There is no reason the spaces can't be eliminated and the formula entered as a single line. 
  For example, the repeated values formula above could also be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({IFERROR(AN6:AN100/0,X3);IFERROR(AN101:AN200/0,Y3);IFERROR(AN201:A300/0,Z3)})
```

## Stack Array 12 Times

```
=TOCOL(ARRAYFORMULA(
   IF(ROW(1:12), 
     TOROW(C3:C100))))
```

- For each row numbered from 1 to 12, return a row populated with the values in `C3:C100`
- Uses TOCOL to convert the 12x98 (HxW) array to a single column with 1,176 rows.

Comment: Ummm.... @Blind Spots, INCREDIBLE. So a couple nuances putting to work. 

For the Repeated Values
- Need a carriage return, or it will spread out to rows
- For the Amount, there weren't instructions, so similar to the property name, I did the amount range (X6:X106),(Y6:Y106)...

Need to iron out sequence and complete, but conceptually all there. See column AU for result.

Comment: @BMCF FYI I didn't visit the link but answered the question based on the details you included in the question.  *"For the Repeated Values - Need a carriage return, or it will spread out to rows"*  I don't understand what this means.  Why would it spread out to rows?   Do you mean that you need a CR in the formula?  The source data? 
 I'm missing something.  Please also edit your question to include any additional relevant info.  Happy to improve my answer if I can.

Comment: @BMCF I just took a quick look at the your sheet and it seems like this might be an example of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)  Seems like a lot of duplication and separate formulas that should be combined.  If you edit the question to include what you actually want to do there is likely a simpler solution with fewer moving parts.    It seems like `C:E` are the source data with some hardcoded values in row 3 and row 4  and everything else is calculated from there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would like to *unpivot* the "wide" data so that it is "tall" and row-oriented, like this:

| Full name | GL account | Property | Total cost | Property | Percentage | Dollars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Noah Olivia | Manager | ST | $211 | ST | 100% | $211 |
| Liam Emma | Renovation | OPP | $509 | OPP | 100% | $509 |
| Oliver Amelia | Repairs & Maintenance | NE | $730 | NE | 100% | $730 |
| Elijah Sophia | Renovation | NE | $767 | NE | 100% | $767 |
| Mateo Ava | Repairs & Maintenance | CS | $416 | CS | 100% | $416 |
| Lucas Charlotte | Renovation | RW | $640 | RW | 100% | $640 |
| Leo Isabella | Manager | PV | $705 | PV | 100% | $705 |
| Ezra Mia | Renovation | NE | $443 | NE | 100% | $443 |
| Levi Luna | Renovation | OPP | $573 | OPP | 100% | $573 |
| James Aurora | Renovation | Custom | $359 | NE | 33% | $120 |
| James Aurora | Renovation | Custom | $359 | GL | 33% | $120 |
| James Aurora | Renovation | Custom | $359 | RW | 33% | $120 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The first four columns are repeated, but instead of "12 times" they are repeated only as many times as required to include all data in the `Percentage` and `Dollars` columns.

To do that, choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=let( 
  header, 'Payroll export'!A3:AL3, 
  data, filter('Payroll export'!A6:AL, len('Payroll export'!C6:C)), 

  cols_, lambda(d, choosecols(d, 
    sequence(1, columns('Payroll export'!C3:F3), column('Payroll export'!C3)), 
    torow(
      vstack(
        sequence(1, columns('Payroll export'!H3:U3), column('Payroll export'!H3)), 
        sequence(1, columns('Payroll export'!X3:AK3), column('Payroll export'!X3)) 
      ), 
      0, true 
    ) 
  )), 

  unpivot_, lambda(data, numFixedCols, numColsPerGroup, let(k,n(numFixedCols),d,if(k,data,hstack(sequence(rows(data)),data)),f,if(k,k,1),g,numColsPerGroup,r_,lambda(t,o,h,chooserows(t,sequence(h,1,o))),c_,lambda(t,o,w,choosecols(t,sequence(1,w,o))),s_,lambda(r,c,h,w,r_(c_(d,c,w),r,h)),h,hstack(s_(1,1,1,f),"Property","Percentage","Dollars"),i,sequence(1,(columns(d)-f)/g,f+1,g),a,reduce(h,sequence(rows(d)-1,1,2),lambda(a,r,let(x,s_(r,1,1,f),b,reduce(tocol(æ,2),i,lambda(y,c,let(z,s_(r,c,1,g),if(single(z)="",y,vstack(y,hstack(x,s_(1,c,1,1),z)))))),vstack(a,b)))),if(k,a,choosecols(a,sequence(1,columns(a)-1,2))))), 

  table, vstack(cols_(header), cols_(data)), 

  unpivot_(table, 4, 2) 
)
```

You can then re-pivot the data to get the reports you want. Use **Insert > Pivot table** or `query()` formulas like this:

```
=query( 
  A1:G, 
  "select B, sum(G) 
   where B is not null 
   group by B 
   pivot E 
   format sum(G) '$0.00' ", 
  1 
)
```

This example `query()` gives are simple report that looks like this:

| GL account | CC | CS | FV | GA | GL | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Accounting & Legal |  |  | $76.85 |  | $76.85 | ... |
| Administrative | $38.56 | $64.68 | $237.33 | $74.32 | $208.41 | ... |
| Landscaping |  |  |  |  |  | ... |
| Manager | $613.40 | $440.20 | $95.50 | $789.40 | $38.20 | ... |
| Renovation | $31.58 | $202.91 | $31.51 | $31.51 | $151.16 | ... |
| Repairs & Maintenance |  | $416.00 |  | $429.00 |  | ... |